# Freeing Memory after Linked List Removal

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I am learning C in my free time. I am familiar with C#, Java, and Python. As an exercise, I wrote a linked list in C. It functions correctly, has error handling, etc.

However, I am trying to fix memory leaks. I know that C does not have automatic garbage collection. So how do I "free" a member of a list after I have removed it? I wrote a function called removeAllList(). The function removes the member from the list successfully, but I know that the memory for that member is still allocated. I have tried using the free([myArgument]) function, but it results in infinite loops. Can you show where I would use the free() function to successfully deallocate memory for the removed member in my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Member{
    int data;
    struct Member *next;
};

struct List{
    int size;
    struct Member *root;
};

struct Member *createMember(int i){
    struct Member *new;

    new = malloc(sizeof(struct Member));
    new->data = i;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

struct List *createList(int i){
    struct List *new;

    new = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    new->root = createMember(i);
    new->size = 1;
    return new;
}

void printList(struct List *list){
    struct Member *current = list->root;

    //error handling for empty list
    if(list->size < 1){
        printf("Error: List is empty");
    }
    //if list is not empty
    else{
        printf("List size: %i\nContents: ", list->size);
        while(current->next != NULL){
            printf("%i, ", current->data);
            current = current->next;
        }
        printf("%i\n", current->data);
    }
}

void addList(struct List *list, int i){
    struct Member *current = list->root;

    while(current->next != NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = createMember(i);
    list->size++;
}

void removeAllList(struct List *list, int i){
    struct Member *current = list->root;
    struct Member *prev = list->root;

    if(list->size < 1){
        //list is empty, end function now
        return;
    }

    //remove all matching list head
    while(current->data == i){
        if(list->size <= 1){
            list->root = NULL;
            list->size--;
            //list is empty, end function now
            return;
        }
        else{
            list->root = current->next;
            current = list->root;
            list->size--;
        }
    }
    current = current->next;

    //remove all matching list body
    while(current->next != NULL && list->size > 1){
        if(current->data == i){
            prev->next = current->next;
            list->size--;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    //remove all matching list tail
        if(current->data == i && list->size > 1){
            prev->next = NULL;
            list->size--;
        }
}

main(){
        struct List *myList; 
        myList = createList(4);
        addList(myList, 12);
    addList(myList, 9);
    addList(myList, 4);
    addList(myList, 43);
    addList(myList, 4);
        printList(myList);
    removeAllList(myList, 4);
    printList(myList);
}
```

Comment: have you tried `man 3 free` and `man malloc` for information?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't make things that consume memory `NULL`. You need to `free()` them like this: `free(mynode->next);` but only when you're sure there was a `malloc()` call before.

In your code, you need to use `free(list->root);` instead of `list->root = NULL;` and `free(prev->next);` instead of `prev->next = NULL;`